# Published App in Open Beta testing (1000 capped) now want to move to Closed Beta

Tags: android, testing, google-play, publishing

Android > Google playstore > Open to Closed beta migration.

I have "X" number of users in Open Beta testing (Anyone with access to the link can installed) with no of users capped at 1000.
Now I want to move to Closed Beta Testing, wherein I will add those email address and they have to become a tester to use/install the App.
How should I proceed ? Ways and options pls.
Adding my view: If I move to Closed Beta, Google says that all the existing users wont have access to the installed app, but then If I add those email address again after moving to Closed Beta, will it solve my purpose, of keeping the users intact.

Peace Out!
Help your fellow hooman here

Answer (score 0):

What if you updated the app to show the user a screen where they can put in their email address if they want to keep using the app?

Then, after a week or so you make it closed beta and everyone who provided his email address can still use the app.

Or doesn't this work?

Comment: I already have their email ids, its part of sign-up to use the app

Comment: @nightcoder Oooh sorry, I misunderstood your question. I swapped "will it" and thought that you know that it will work. Well no, then I can't help you I'm sorry :(